# how do you set a baseURL in an angular 2 application

Tags: angular

In my index.html I have the following import ->

```
<script>
   System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
      System.import('main');
   }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

In system-config.ts I have the following at the beginning of the file ->

```
import { environment } from './app';

const packages: any = {};
System.config({baseURL : environment.cdnBaseUrl});
```

It blows up on the import line so I can't even get to setting the baseURL.  This is an "angularCLI" project using angular 2.  Essentially, if the baseURL isn't set then it uses the default URL from the server that the page is initially loaded from.  I need a different URL to point to the CDN to load all the front end stuff.. html/css/js/angular files.

Comment: This may be a bit skinny to give you a good answer. Could you make a plunker or similar?

Comment: working up a small example

Comment: fixed it by using _> System.import('${cdnBaseUrl}/app/environment.js').then(function(environment){
            System.config({ baseUrl: environment.cdnBaseURL });
            System.import('${cdnBaseUrl}/system-config.js').then(function () {
                System.import('main');
            }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
        });

Comment: ember gives clear documentation on how to use a CDN of setting baseURL -> http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/04/28/baseURL.html.  Section "How to use a CDN" .. wish angular CLI gave good documentation

Comment: article on deprecation of baseURL -> https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/290